# jQuery Isotope animation NOT working but filtering IS working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I installed isotope on a website I'm developing yesterday. It was working fine up until an hour ago. The filters work, but the animations have stopped.

I'm not sure what would cause the animations to stop working. I haven't changed anything on the site. The code is located in the footer, but I've provided it below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        var $container = $('#main-home');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: '*',
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });

        $('#filters a').click(function(){
            $('#filters .selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
             });
             return false;
        }); 
    });
    </script>
```

If anyone has any advice I really appreciate your help. This is my first time implementing Isotope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I went to this page: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html and added the CSS into the website.

For some reason it was working without the CSS, not sure why I had to add it after animations were working fine beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for this - I had a similar problem but had no idea why the sorting was working, but not animating!

Answer (score 0):

If you set:

```
animationEngine: 'best-available'
```

Isotope choose the Animation between CSS3 Transition and jQuery animate()

You can now find the Animation Description and the CSS code here: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/animating.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add  following styles to project.

```
.isotope-item {
    z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.isotope,
.isotope .isotope-item {
    /* change duration value to whatever you like */
    -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .7s;
    transition-duration: .7s;
}

.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```